# Laravel 4.2 custom validator to combine required_if OR required_without

Tags: php, validation, required, laravel-4.2

Let me describe my scenario. Here's a form similar to mine:

```
<select name="colors">
  <option value="1">Dark red</option>
  <option value="2">Light red</option>
  <option value="3">Dark green</option>
  <option value="4">Light green</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="textbox-field">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-field" value="1">
```

I'd like to validate `textbox-field` OR `checkbox-field` based on which value is selected on `colors`. The problem is that `textbox-field` and `checkbox-field` are mutually exclusive, which means that only one of them has to be filled when the specified `colors` values have been selected.

If I had one field I could just use the built-in required_if rule like this:

```
'textbox-field' => "string|required_if:colors,3,4"
```

However, what I want to achieve is somethink like this but with an OR operator between the last two rules:

```
'textbox-field'  => "string|required_if:colors,3,4|required_without:checkbox-field"
'checkbox-field' => "numeric|required_if:colors,3,4|required_without:textbox-field"
```

Is it possible to create a custom validation rule which will combine required_if  and required_without using the OR logical operator?

Comment: AS i know rules combined with and, so you can write your own validtation rule.

Comment: That's true, any assistance on how can I implement a custom validation for this case? Is it possible to use built-in validation rules inside a custom one?

Comment: Just to answer my own questions from above, yes it is possible to use built-in rules inside a new custom validator as long as it is implemented inside a class that extends the `Illuminate\Validation\Validator`. This way it will have access to protected functions that implement all the built-in rules like `validateRequiredIf()` and `validateRequiredWithout`. Check the code below for a specific example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out, by implementing the following custom validator:

```
/**
 * Class CustomValidator
 * Extends the Illuminate\Validation\Validator class instead of using Validator::extend,
 * it requires access to protected properties of the Validator parent class
 *
 * Note: This needs to be registered in app/start/global.php
 */
class CustomValidator extends Illuminate\Validation\Validator
{

/**
 * The validation rules that imply the field is required.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $implicitRules = array(
    'Required',
    'RequiredWith',
    'RequiredWithAll',
    'RequiredWithout',
    'RequiredWithoutAll',
    'RequiredIf',
    'Accepted',
    'RequiredIfValueSelectedOrWithoutField'
);
/**
 * Validate mutually exclusive fields when specific options have been selected in select input
 * This uses the built-in rules and apply them using the OR logical operator
 *
 * @param $attribute
 * @param $value
 * @param $parameters
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function validateRequiredIfValueSelectedOrWithoutField($attribute, $value, $parameters) {

    // use the required_if bult-in rule to check if the required options are selected in select input
    $valueSelectedParams = array_merge(['my_select_input'],Model::getArrayWithTheSpecifiedOptions());
    $isValidForSelect = $this->validateRequiredIf($attribute, $value, $valueSelectedParams);

    // use the required_without to check if the mutually exclusive field in parameters[0] has a value
    $isValidForMutualExclusiveField = $this->validateRequiredWithout($attribute, $value, [$parameters[0]]);

    // returns the result by applying OR between the required_if and the required_without rules
    return ($isValidForSelect || $isValidForMutualExclusiveField);
}

/**
 * Replace the :other placeholder with the select input localized literal to display correctly in error messages
 *
 * @param $message
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function replaceDangerousEkaOrField($message)
{
    return str_replace(':other', Lang::get('model.my_select_input'), $message);
}
```

I placed this in `app/helpers/CustomValidator.php` and registered it at the end of my `app/start/global.php`:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Custom Validator extending Illuminate\Validation\Validator
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
{
    return new CustomValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
});
```

It also required to run `composer dump-autoload` to add the new class to classloader.

I hope this to help anyone in a similar position in the future. Cheers!